# Can we use a Wilcoxon signed rank test on discrete, non-normal data in a small sample size?

Tags: normal-distribution, discrete-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am looking to validate my decision to use a wilcoxon signed rank test to test for significance in my study.

Essentially, I have a small sample size (n=10) and the data is paired. I am looking to see if there is a significant difference in a student's SAT scores before and after taking a prep course.

Test scores should be discrete data, and with such a small sample size, I cant assume that it is normally distributed. Can I use a wilcoxon signed rank test in this scenario?

Comment: If the samples are truly paired, the pre and post scores from each student, then the pair t-test is the better test.  Do you have any evidence to suspect that the difference between the pre & post would not be normally distributed?

Comment: Hi Dave2e, I was not sure about the t-test, because I can't understand what I need to normalize. Would I need to normalize the entire data set, or to normalize each pre and post group separately? Since the sample size is so small, and the population is almost certainly right skewed (the population has a stronger right tail, trust me on this) I thought that a non parametric test would be better.

Comment: I may not fully understand your study.  If the study collected the pre scores, performed a treatment and collected the post scores to see if the treatment improved the scores, then the likely best test is a paired t.test.  There is no need to normalize anything here.  For a paired t.test, take the difference between the pre & post for the 10 students (this difference, will like be normal) and perform the t.test with test if the mean of differences = 0.    If this is still not clear, please edit your question and add additional detail, may even the results themselves.